# Auto enable preserve log in chrome over nightmare

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, nightmare

Who to automaticaly enable preserve log checkbox in chrome devtools network panel using nightmare?
Current options for developer tools:

```
let devoptions = {
    show: true,
    openDevTools: {
        mode: 'detach'
    },
    webPreferences: {
        partition: 'nopersist',
    }
}
```